# Publishing Artifacts a,b,c as a.zip, b.zip, c.zip

Tags: teamcity, artifacts

I have a TeamCity build on which other builds depend. This build produces some output inside a directory, e.g. output_dir/dir1, output_dir/dir2, output_dir/dir3.

Is there any way of getting these 3 directories zipped separately as dir1.zip, dir2.zip, dir3.zip? I need something like `output_dir/dir* => dir*.zip`

I can manually enter all the paths but I'd rather it's scalable and automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an out-of-the-box solution for this. However, I would try using the build parameter instead of the hardcoded artifact patterns. This is what I mean:

- On the ***General Settings > Artifacts paths*** enter some build parameter reference:

[image]

- Set that build parameter to an empty string
- Create a build step, e.g. PowerShell, which is devoted to producing the real artifact paths patterns, like `output_dir/dir1 => dir1.zip, output_dir/dir2 => dir2.zip`, etc.
- As the last step of that PowerShell script, use [the TeamCity service message](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html#Adding+or+Changing+a+Build+Parameter) to set the `%artifact.pattern%` build parameter to that generated value.

I haven't tried it myself, to be honest, but the fact that `Artifacts paths` field supports build parameters makes me think this might be possible. Of course, you might realize that's too much of a hassle, and updating the value manually wasn't that bad of an idea ;)